# Fast way to get number of changed/deleted lines per subset of files per commit

Tags: python, git, optimization, diff, gitpython

I am doing some source code analysis with GitPython.
For each commit I look at the contents of each .java file like this:

```py
from git import Repo 
repo = Repo.init('/path/to/repo', bare=True)
for commit in repo.iter_commits():
    for obj in commit.tree.traverse(predicate = lambda obj, depth: obj.type == 'blob' and obj.name.endswith('.java')):
        content = obj.data_stream.read().decode("CP437")
        #...
```

This works already really fast and reliable.
However, when I try to additionally get the number of changed and deleted lines of code for those files, it gets much slower. More precisely, I tried `commit.stats.files` which internally calls `git diff --numstat`. This is basically exactly what I want (I can easily filter for .java files), but for a repo where the above code takes ~5s, adding `commit.stats.files` increases time to ~140s which is infeasible for larger repos.

So my question is: Do you have ideas for a clever and fast way of getting the diff lines of code for all .java files for all commits? 
I do not need the full diffs, just the number of lines...

It would be nice to not increase the run time of the old code by more than factor 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `git log --numstat` or `git log --numstat > stats.txt` in your terminal.

If running time is acceptable :

- check if running the same command from gitpython is ok perfromance wise too (`git = new Git(...); git.log('-numstat', ...)` (if not acceptable : run the command using `os.exec ...`)
- parse the output of this command

Comment: Thank you, nice solution! I am using `git log --numstat --format=//%H` so I have an easy to split format ('//' should not occur in file paths on any normal os, right?).

Comment: An additional interesting thing to note maybe:
`repo.iter_commits()` internally calls `git rev-list` (which is what takes 90% of its run time apparently) which can now be ommitted as we get all commits from the `git log`. 
Plus, having the detailed diff information for each commit, I am sure I can optimize my code even further by only taking the changed files into account.